# Java array of objects,arraylist of objects problem

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist

I'm taking my first programming course in college, and my problem is the following:

I've got an ArrayList of Player objects having the following properties:

```
name: String; 
area: int; 
numberofdices: int;
```

For each player, the `Area` is Initialized as 8, and `NumberOfDices` is initialized as 24.

I want to pass these Players to a 2D array. So, for example, if there are 3 players, I want the array to look something like this:

```
[ 
    [name: 1, area: 8, numberofdices: 3], 
    [name: 2, area: 8, numberofdices: 2], 
    [name: 3, area: 8, numberofdices: 8]
]
```

Essentially, I want all Players to have Area as 8, and I want to divide the NumberOfDices randomly between the Area. (Min 1, Max 8)

**Tried the following** but it didn't work:

```
    public static void random_board(ArrayList<Players> listofplayers,Players[][] gameboard) {
        do {
            for(int row = 0;row < gameboard.length;row++) {
                for(int column = 0;column < gameboard[row].length;column++) {
                    // System.out.println(gameboard[row][column]);
                    if(gameboard[row][column] == null) {
                        Iterator<Players> it = listofplayers.iterator();
                        while (it.hasNext()) {
                            Players i = it.next();
                            Random r = new Random();
                            int number = r.nextInt(8) + 1;

                            if (i instanceof Players) {
                                if (((Players) i).numberofdices - number >= 1 && ((Players i).area  > 1) {
                                    gameboard[row][column] =  new Players(((Players) i).name, 1, number);
                                    ((Players) i).setnumberofdices(((Players) i).getnumberofdices() - number);
                                    ((Players) i).setarea(i.getarea()-1);

                                    if ( ((Players)i).getarea() == 1 ) {
                                        gameboard[row][column] = new Players(((Players)i).name,((Players)i).area,((Players)i).numberofdices);
                                        it.remove();

                                    }
                                }
                            } else if (i instanceof Enemies) {
                                if (((Enemies) i).numberofdices - number >= 1 && ((Enemies) i).area  > 1) {
                                    gameboard[row][column] =  new Enemies(((Enemies) i).name, 1, number,((Enemies)i).getAttacking_mood());
                                    ((Enemies) i).setnumberofdices(((Enemies) i).getnumberofdices() - number);
                                    ((Enemies) i).setarea(i.getarea()-1);

                                    if ( ((Enemies)i).getarea() == 1 ) {
                                        gameboard[row][column] = new Enemies(((Enemies)i).name,((Enemies)i).area,((Enemies)i).numberofdices,((Enemies)i).getAttacking_mood());
                                        it.remove();


                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } while (!listofplayers.isEmpty());
```

I have an `Enemies` class that inherits from the `Players` class and contains another member variable: `attacking_mood`.

I think it goes to an infinite loop.

Comment: Unclear what the issue is. Can you you be more specific than "it didn't work"? And why do you think is goes into an infinite loop? It should be easy to test that.

Comment: Needs more code and information about the actual problem. What is the error or output of the program (if there's none, print out variables) ? What does not work specifically ? What are those `Enemies` doing there ? Why is there a `Players` and a `Player` class ?

Comment: Parallel to writing programs, learn how to debug them. E.g. use your IDE's single-stepping feature to follow your program's flow of control. Watch your variables' contents - do they contain the expected values? This way, you'll surely find out what goes wrong, better than anybody else, as nobody knows what to expect better than you do.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses!

i suppose the infinite loop because after i ran the program nothing happened,just loaded for an hour,so i stopped it.

Answer (score 1):

```
   do{} while (!listofplayers.isEmpty()); this Loop will run infinite if listofplayers doesn't become empty
```

Comment: yes,i noticed that too,but it should become empty,because of the "it.remove" part, shouldn't it?